# SnappyData REST API to Submit Job

Tags: apache-spark, snappydata

I am trying to submit Snappy Job using REST API.

- We have been able to submit SnappyJob using snappy-job submit Command
  Line tool.
- I could not find any documentation how to do the same thing through
  REST API.
- I found somewhere mentioned in the forum that SnappyData is using the
  spark jobserver REST API.

  Could you point to the Documentation / User Guide how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snappydata internally uses spark-jobserver for submitting the jobs. Hence, all the spark-jobserver REST APIs are accessible on Snappydata's lead node.

You can refer to all spark-jobserver API here: https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/spark-jobserver#api

Here are some useful curl commands to clarify it further:

- deploy application jar on job-server:

`curl --data-binary @/path/to/applicaton.jar localhost:8090/jars/testApp`

`testApp` is the name of the job server app which will be used to submit the job

- create context:

`curl -X POST "localhost:8090/contexts/testSnappyContext?context-factory=org.apache.spark.sql.SnappySessionFactory"`

`testSnappyContext` is the name of the context which will be used to submit the job.

Also, note that we are passing a custom context-factory argument here which is necessary for submitting snappy job.

- submit the job:

`curl -d "configKey1=configValue1,configKey2=configValue2" "localhost:8090/jobs?appName=testApp&classPath=com.package.Main&context=testSnappyContext"`

`com.package.Main` is the fully-qualified name of the class which is extending `org.apache.spark.sql.SnappySQLJob`.

- stop the job

`curl -X DELETE localhost:8090/jobs/bfed84a1-0b06-47ca-81a7-9b8defb51e38`

`bfed84a1-0b06-47ca-81a7-9b8defb51e38` is the job-id which you will get in the response of job submit request

- stop the context

`curl -X DELETE localhost:8090/contexts/testSnappyContext`

- undeploying the application jar

The version of job-server being used by snappydata doesn't have a RESTful API exposed for undeploying the jar. However, deploying any jar with the same app name (testApp in our example) will override the previously deployed jar for the same app.